# Telegram Bot format of send message

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I have coded a telegram bot in python and one of the commands that I have created sends an array of days and details. The code operates perfectly while executed in python directly (I'm using python3). The output is the following:

```
array=["'17'", "'Turístico'", "'23'", "'Día Libre'"]
```

But when I incorporate the code as a function in the bot's code, the same code creates this output:

```
array=["17", "Tur\u00edsti", "23", "D\u00eda Libre"]
```

The only difference between the two cases is the `bot.send_message` line that replaces the `print` of the array
`bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=array)`

What can I do to pretty print the array as a message in telegram (I know that the send message is intended as text, so if you have a different approach please tell me). I believe that there is an issue with the spanish accents and the utf-8 codification in `bot.send_message`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this  situation by using the `unidecode` module.

So, basically I

```
import unidecode
```

And use this code

```py
array2 = unidecode.unidecode(array)
```

and now `array2` looks like this:

```py
array2 = ["'17'", "'Turistico'", "'23'", "'Dia Libre'"]
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a better way to print an array or a big text in telegram bot rather than using the bot.send_message snippet?